# Php artisan error no direct script access allowed

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy trabajando con **laravel 5.2 y php 7.1.7**, el problema es que cuando trato de usar algún comando de artisan para levantar el servidor con el comando `php artisan serve` me sale:

> no direct script access allowed

en la consola y no me deja iniciar.

También intenté haciendo un `composer clear-cache` y luego `composer update` pero cuando hago el update tambien me sale el:

> no direct script access allowed

y no sé cómo arreglarlo. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo resolvi o al menos por ahora comente la linea `if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');` en mis dos archivos donde aparecian que era en `app/AuthLDAP.php` y en `config/authldap.php`. Parece funcionar por ahora.!

Comment: También podés probar actualizando el instalador de Laravel `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Comment: Vale @MaruAmallo lo intentare ahora gracias.

Comment: Ojo que el instalador te va a intalar L5.5. Si hay alguna razón por la que necesitas usar L 5.2 al momento de crear tu aplicación tenés que hacer `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel NOMBREPROYECTO "5.2.*"`